# Accessing results from another method

Tags: php

Hi I'm relatively new to OOP PHP and trying to get my head around a few concepts. I have two methods one public and one private.

The public function is parameter is being filled by a get value and then it uses the private method to query the database.

```
public function viewProject($id) {

    if (!intval($id)) {
        $this->projectError = 'The requested project must be a numeric value';
        return false;
    }

    if (!$this->findProject($id)) {
        $this->projectError = 'The specified project was not found.';
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private function findProject($pid) {
    $data = $this->_db->get("projects", array('id', "=", $pid));
    return  $data->results();
}
```

I want to be able to store the results from the findProject method in a var like

$this->projectName = //result here for name

However I'm not entirely sure how to access the results from the query in the public method.

Comment: The basics of OOP in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php. What you need is a class attribute to store your values privately, but outside of its method's scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
public function viewProject($id) {
    if (!intval($id)) {
        $this->projectError = 'The requested project must be a numeric value';
        return false;
    }
    $this->$project = $this->findProject($id); //project has the value
    if (!$project) {
        $this->projectError = 'The specified project was not found.';
        return false;
    }



    return true;

}

private function findProject($pid) {
    $data = $this->_db->get("projects", array('id', "=", $pid));
    return  $data->results();

}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Can you explain what you did and why?

Comment: I have just stored the result of the  function call $this->findProject() into $this->project  and that is what he wants

Comment: Clearly the OP isn't very well informed about the basics of OOP, so a little more information might be welcome. Teach him, not just solve his current problem.

Answer (score 1):

All poperties of a class, public, protected and private can be accessed in every method of that class. If you define projectName as a (private) property, it can be accessed in every other method.

Also, your query result is probably a multi-dimensional array, so you have to retrieve the projectName value yourself from the result.

```
class A
{
    protected $projectName;

    public function viewProject($id) {
        if (!intval($id)) {
            $this->projectError = 'The requested project must be a numeric value';
            return false;
        }

        $results = $this->findProject($id);
        if (!$results) {
            $this->projectError = 'The specified project was not found.';
            return false;
        }

        //Parse results
        //assuming $this->_db->get() returns a multi-dimensional array
        //assuming 'projectName' corresponds is the db column name
        $this->projectName = $results[0]['projectName'];

        return true;
    }

    private function findProject($pid) {
        $data = $this->_db->get("projects", array('id', "=", $pid));
        return  $data->results();
    }
}
```